# Re-organizing lists of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and trying to read a large file with position data for objects over a time series. Something like:

```py
for a in dum_un.file:
    
    FD = dum_un.select_object("type 1")
    r = FD.positions
```

Each `r` corresponds to a specific time point, and each list-within-the-list corresponds to the x, y, and z positions of an object at that time point. The ordering is the same throughout the time series. Example for 2 objects:

First iteration of the for loop: `r = [[1.11, 2.64, 3.3],[4.0, 5.12, 6.32]]`

Second iteration of the for loop: `r = [[5.7, 4.44, 1.8],[6.3, 8.9, 4.7]]`

I want to be able to access a list of all x (or y or z) values for each object over the entire time series, e.g., here:

`x = [1.11, 5.7]` for object 1

`x = [4.0, 6.3]` for object 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way.

The parsing creates a dictionary called `objects` that looks something like this:

```json
{
  "1": {
    "x": [1.11, 5.7],
    "y": [...],
    "z": [...],
  },
  "2": {
    "x": [...],
    "y": [...],
    "z": [...],
  },
  ...
}
```

Here's the code:

```py
# This list represents the value of `r` in each iteration
all_r = [
    [[1.11, 2.64, 3.3],[4.0, 5.12, 6.32]],
    [[5.7, 4.44, 1.8],[6.3, 8.9, 4.7]]
]

# Initialise a dictionary to collect all the results
# The key for each entry will be the object "ID"
# e.g. the first item in `r` represents "object 1".
objects = dict()

for r in all_r:
    for i, coordinates in enumerate(r):
        # Python indexes start at zero. So increment by one to match your definition
        object_id = str(i + 1)
    
        # Initialise the dictionary key for our object if it doesn't exist already
        if object_id not in objects.keys():
            objects[object_id] = {
                "x": [],
                "y": [],
                "z": [],
            }

        # Add each co-ordinate to their relevant X, Y or Z list
        objects[object_id]["x"].append(coordinates[0])
        objects[object_id]["y"].append(coordinates[1])
        objects[object_id]["z"].append(coordinates[2])

expected_x_object_1 = [1.11, 5.7]
expected_x_object_2 = [4.0, 6.3]

actual_x_object_1 = objects.get("1", dict()).get("x", None)
actual_x_object_2 = objects.get("2", dict()).get("x", None)

assert expected_x_object_1 == actual_x_object_1
assert expected_x_object_2 == actual_x_object_2
```

Comment: Thanks. However, that seems to give all of the x (or y or z) values for a given `r` for all objects at a particular time point. Sorry if I was unclear: I would like to have all of the x (or y or z) values over the entire time series for each object.

Comment: @user2 your requirements aren't clear to me, I'm afraid! Can you update your original question with the expected outputs given your sample value of `r`, please?

Comment: Done. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Any luck with the updated code, @user2 ?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!!! Sorry for the bit of a delayed response.